# Ajax call to php, get mysql data as array and use in JS function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I'm looking to make an ajax call to a PHP script to get data from MySQL, create a json array and pass it back to the success function of the ajax call, where i will then use it as parameters for a JavaScript function.

This is my ajax call,

```
    $('button[name="message"]').click(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
    var $tenant_id = $row.find(".col-md-1 id").text(); // Find the tenants ID
    var $landlord_id = "<?php echo $id; ?>"
    $.ajax({
        url : "./message.php",
        type : "POST",
        async : false,
        data: {
        landlord_id: $landlord_id,
        tenant_id : $tenant_id
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var messages = data;
            insertChat(messages.sender_id, messages.body, messages.timestamp);
        }
        })
});
```

And this is my PHP file,

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once('../dbconnect.php');
    // update tenants table to show deposit returned
    if(isset($_POST['tenant_id'])){
    $tenant_id = $_POST['tenant_id'];
    $landlord_id = $_POST['landlord_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from messages  WHERE messages.sender_id OR messages.receiver_id = '$tenant_id' AND messages.sender_id OR messages.receiver_id = '$landlord_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));

    //create an array
    $messages = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $messages[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($messages);

}
    ?>
```

If anybody has a link to a tutorial or the individual parts that would be fantastic. I don't even know if the process i have outlined above is correct. 
If anybody could tell me the correct way to go about this that would be of great help!

Thanks

Comment: Your logic seems to be good, don't forget the `JSON.parse(data)` in your success

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  What happens when you run the above?  FYI, asking for links to tutorials is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the internet. You can find them easy with google. This site is for helping you when you get stuck on the tutorials, not to request sources.

Comment: Well one 'correct' way to go about it, would be to use prepared statements for the SQL portion so you are not open to sql injection attacks. The rest is subjective to how you like to deal with ajax calls.

Comment: Apologies, i didn't know tutorial sourcing was off topic. Basically i am getting "undefined" when i try and pass the data to the javascript function.

Comment: @RomainB. if i use JSON.parse on the data i get an empty array. Must i use a for loop to iterate over the array or something similar?

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools and look at the response.  Is it what you expect?  If not, then you need to start by debugging your PHP.  Before you do that though, you should really take IncredibleHat's advice and start using prepared statements with bound parameters.

Comment: Add `dataType: 'JSON',` to your `.ajax` options, and also it looks like you are sending back an array of messages, so you need to reference `var messages = data[0];` instead.

Comment: @D.Neligan what is your `console.log(data)` returning? And you shouldn't name your variables $something, check this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp :)

Comment: @RomainB. ... I'd agreed. Seeing the `$` in front of js vars, makes me think they are a full object, not a string/int var. His `var $row` is ok, since it is an object. The id vars arn't though... confusing to look at ;)

Comment: @RomainB. console.log returns [{"id":"1","sender_id":"4","receiver_id":"5","body":"This is a short message from shane frewen","is_read":"0","timestamp":"2018-02-24 23:27:38"}]

Comment: @D.Neligan ok so just do as @IncredibleHat said : `var messages = data[0]` and you'll get your values ^^

Comment: @IncredibleHat That works perfectly, thanks very much. I was trying a loop previously but i was doing data.sender_id[i] as opposed to the loop on the data. Thanks very much! I will go about using prepared statements now, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few things to adjust your javascript side (I won't explain the php sql injection issue you have... but please research `prepare`, `bind_param` and `execute`):

1. Since you are returning an ARRAY of `$messages` from php (json_encoded), you need to loop on those in your `success` handler.
2. Add `dataType: 'JSON'` to your options, so it explicitly expects json returned from php.
3. And you were missing a couple semicolons ;)

Adjustments added to your code:

```
$('button[name="message"]').click(function() {
    var $row        = $(this).closest("tr");
    var tenant_id   = $row.find(".col-md-1 id").text();
    var landlord_id = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
    $.ajax({
        url : "./message.php",
        type : "POST",
        data: {
            landlord_id: landlord_id,
            tenant_id : tenant_id
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (typeof data !== undefined) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    insertChat(data[i].sender_id, data[i].body, data[i].timestamp);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```